# Bengali font is not showing in pdf report from grails

Tags: grails, jasper-reports, grails-2.0, grails-plugin, jasper-plugin

I want to generate a pdf report from my application. I am using grails 2.1.1 version. My pdf file will show some bengali font which is done in ireport designer. For this I have installed the font. And for doing this from my application I have saved the font as jar in the lib folder of my application. But when I generate the report Bengali font is not shown in the report. Can anyone please help me on this please ? I have searched in google for it but no luck at all. thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you created jar file from iReport designer?

Comment: yes I did maybe its an OS problem. I did not check it lately cause busy in other project